# Open SSO Authentication failure when invoking via Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, cookies, glassfish, token, opensso

I am an Oracle Developer, we have a requirement to read the contents of a filenet documents via oracle database , but OpenSSO is enabled in our environments which is currently blocking us to read the data from filenet server.

While checking with OpenSSO guys , they confirmed that while invoking the filenet URL via browser , a session cookie gets generated in OpenSSO which plays a significant role in authentication.

But , when we tried to invoke the same filenet URL via Oracle pl/sql ( i.e database) , we could see the cookie details as below. However, we don't understand , why opensso was still not showing  'successful authentication'.
We googled the error code X-AuthErrorCode: -1 which says  "In the response you're going to receive "X-autherrorcode" header, if it's value 0, then the login was successful. Also, you need to check the
iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie for admin session id".
With all these information, can someone please help us in getting the root cause of the authentication failure in OpenSSO?

```
   HTTP response status code: 200
   HTTP response reason phrase: OK
   X-Powered-By: JSP/2.1
   Server: Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1
   Cache-Control: private
   Pragma: no-cache
   Expires: 0
   X-DSAMEVersion: (2011-March-02 18:42)
   AM_CLIENT_TYPE: genericHTML
   Set-Cookie: 
   AMAuthCookie=AQIC5wM2LY4SfcyXSVnslvF7a5TLMa4KXz5Op9tRKzczinU.*AAJTSQACMDE. 
  *; Domain=.companyname.co.uk; Path=/
  Set-Cookie: amlbcookie=01; Domain=.companyname.co.uk; Path=/
  X-AuthErrorCode: -1
  Set-Cookie: AMAuthCookie=LOGOUT; Domain=.companyname.co.uk; 
  Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=286b0c94d89dffd4f602831969ae; Path=/opensso; 
  Secure
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
  Date: Fri, 24 Oct 2014 14:19:23 GMT
  Connection: close
```

### While downloading a Text file from filenet, we got the content as below

HTTP Status 401 -
type Status report
message
descriptionThis request requires HTTP authentication ().
Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1

Can someone please help me at the earliest to get a solution for this ? Is this really possible to make the authentication success via oracle database packages rather than invoking the URL via browser ? if it is possible what should be next step I need to do  ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Remya Sudhakaran